# How to pass variable around functions within plugin's Observer.php?

Tags: php, magento

In my plugin's `Model/Observer.php` I have 2 functions which are corresponding to 2 different events, but I want to pass a variable from first function to next one. I tried something like this:

```
class ContactologyProduct_LogProductUpdate_Model_Observer
{

(...)

public function beforeAddressSave(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

  $contactologyClientIdBeforeEdit = $this->getCustomerAddress();

  $this->setData('contactologyClientIdBeforeEdit', $contactologyClientIdBeforeEdit);  // won't work

}

public function afterAddressSave(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

  $contactologyClientIdAfterEdit = $this->getCustomerAddress();

  $contactologyClientIdBeforeEdit = $this->getData('contactologyClientIdBeforeEdit');  // won't work

  var_dump($contactologyClientIdBeforeEdit); // won't work
  var_dump($contactologyClientIdAfterEdit);

}

}
```

but `setData()` doesn't work, I get error:

```
Call to a member function setData() on a non-object
```

Which way would be the proper one to save `$contactologyClientIdBeforeEdit` in `beforeAddressSave()` function, so that it could be accessed later in `afterAddressSave()`?

Comment: Use `$observer` instead of `$this` in `setData()`

Comment: Not sure about what you're doing here, but I see no `setData` method, and I suspect you're overlooking the fact that objects are passed by reference. If function A receives an object, and passes that to function B, which edits that same object, then the object in function A is modified, too

Answer (score 0):

```
public function beforeAddressSave(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
   $contactologyClientIdBeforeEdit = $this->getCustomerAddress();
   $this->setData('contactologyClientIdBeforeEdit', $contactologyClientIdBeforeEdit);  // won't work
}
```

You should use $observer instead of $this, but fist you should look where the event is created, since you can have something like:

```
$contactologyClientIdBeforeEdit = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomerAddress();
```

Then you can implement the setData and getData in your class, or have your class extend Varien_Object class.
So, I think you will have:

```
class ContactologyProduct_LogProductUpdate_Model_Observer extends Varien_Object {
public function beforeAddressSave(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
   $contactologyClientIdBeforeEdit = $observer->getCustomerAddress(); //or $observer->getEvent()->getCustomerAddress() look how the event data is set.
   $this->setData('contactologyClientIdBeforeEdit', $contactologyClientIdBeforeEdit);
}
public function afterAddressSave(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
   $contactologyClientIdAfterEdit = $observer->getCustomerAddress();
   $contactologyClientIdBeforeEdit = $this->getData('contactologyClientIdBeforeEdit');
}
```

Comment: `$this->getCustomerAddress()` was ok - there is no need to change that to `$observer->getCustomerAddress()`. Anyway, `$this->getData('contactologyClientIdBeforeEdit')` (I tried also `observer` instead of `this`) still returns value only in first function (where it was set), in second one it returns `NULL`.

Comment: I checked `$this` with `var_dump()` and it appears that it refers to 2 different observers, before address edit: `#132`, after address edit: `#368`...

Comment: Unless you're doing something else in the class, $this is a reference to ContactologyProduct_LogProductUpdate_Model_Observer. If you changed the code to extend Varien_Object it will have access to methods like setData and getData. Otherwise I don't see how `$this->getCustomerAddress()` would be defined and return something. Anyway you can user `Mage::register($key, $value);` where `$key` can be 'contactologyClientIdBeforeEdit' and `$value` the data from `$observer->getCustomerAddress()` instead of setData() and for getData() you can have `Mage::registry($key)`

Comment: yeah, `getCustomerAddress()` is my own function. Mage registry works the same as `set/get Data` - returns value in first function, but `NULL` in second one.

Comment: `var_dump(Mage::registry("contactologyClientIdBeforeEdit"));`

Comment: like I said, in 1st function it's a string, in 2nd function it's `NULL`

Comment: are you in the same request?

Comment: guess not, but eventually I've managed to make it work using session variable

Comment: You should have started with that.
Information set with registry and setData (without save in db) are available only on that run of the script. So if you want them to be persistent you have to use something for storage (session, cookie, database, cache...)